# Как правильно: "нет" и "нету"?

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли слово "нету" литературным? И, если да, в каких ситуациях уместно его употреблять? А то как-то попалась дискуссия на эту тему, где некоторые товарищи плевались на это слово, как некоторые плюются на слово "кушать".
Спасибо

Comment: "нет" и "нету", "с ней" и "с нею" ("с нейу"), "Только посмей!" и "И посмею.", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лексика разговорной речи дифференцируется по степени литературности. Можно выделить следующие разновидности разговорной лексики: общеупотребительная, собственно разговорная и просторечная, выходящая за границы литературного языка.

В целом разговорный стиль относится к устной форме существования языка, поэтому не характерен для письменной речи, не считая художественной литературы и публицистической, в которой передается устная речь персонажей. Уместен он также в дружеских письмах (не официальных) и в ситуациях неформального общения.

Просторечный вариант разговорного *нету* - *нетути*.

Answer (score 10):

Слово есть. В словарях зафиксировано тоже (и у Ушакова, и у Ожегова, и у Ефремовой). Слово литературное, но уместно его употребление только в разговорном стиле. (Чтобы не было недопонимания: разговорный стиль - стиль литературного языка. Употребляется в неофициальной обстановке, преимущественно в устной форме). Т.е., например, дома членам семьи вы можете сказать:"Нету денег!". Если  то же самое вы напишете в документе или скажете в официальной обстановке, это будет стилистически неверным употреблением.

Answer (score 8):

Насчёт употребления. 
Смысл слова "нету" — это не отрицание, это указание на отсутствие чего-либо (как, например, "there is no" в английском или "no hay" в испанском). Соответственно, и употребляться оно может в ситуациях, когда, к примеру, вас спрашивают, есть ли у вас что-то:

— У тебя есть карандаш?
 — Нету.

А в следующем примере может использоваться только "нет":

— Ты пойдёшь с нами в кино?
— Нет!

"Нету" в данном случае неприменимо.

Comment: *"Нету" в данном случае неприменимо.* — точнее сказать, в этом значении "нету" устарело (настолько, что даже и раньше не фиксировалось словарями). Но в разговорной речи использовалось (см. пример в "Евгении Онегине" у А.С.Пушкина).

Comment: @grizzly: что там в "Евгении Онегине"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: Там такое: «...Представь меня». — Ты шутишь. — «Нету». Такую цитату обычно приводят в словарях к этому значению слова *нету*.

Comment: Спасибо! Удивительно! Как интересно было это узнать!!!

Comment: @grizzly: а не знаете, почему реплики Ленского без кавычек, а Онегина в кавычках? Вроде, когда прямая речь с помощью тире, кавычек не бывает. Или в стихах по-другому? Если не знаете, задам вопрос отдельно (но отпишитесь, пожалуйста, в любом случае).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Нет, не знаю. В разных изданиях по-разному, но я посмотрел в своём добротном бумажном издании и так процитировал. Но вот, например, когда А.Зализняк цитировал эти строчки в своих "берестяных грамотах", он кавычек нигде не ставил (кстати, там же он говорил, что нет оснований сомневаться в древности и вторичности этого значения **нету**).

Comment: Вторичность это как?

Answer (score 2):

Ещё как является! Какие-то "грамотеи" придумали, что слово просторечное, а между тем "нет" - это отрицание для ответа на вопрос, а с помощью "нету" говорят об отсутствии чего-либо.

"Нет, я не смогу одолжить тебе денег" и "У меня самого перед получкой денег совсем нету".

Также с помощью "нету" часто можно ёмко, коротко и односложно ответить на несколько вопросов.

> - А у вас было поступление товара? Есть в наличии красные стулья?
> - Нету.

Если здесь ответить "нет", то придётся уточнять: нет, не было поступления или нет, в наличии красных стульев нет - выглядят такие конструкции громоздко и неуклюже. Но зато "грамотно" с точки зрения норм. Парадокс.

P.s. Как правильно заметили сверху, в других языках есть аналогичные конструкции для этой же цели - сказать, что чего-то или кого-то нет. В английском есть "no" и "there is no". Но у них также иногда наблюдается использование "no" вместо "there is no", только с другой целью - для уменьшения количества слов. В русском же языке в этом нет никакого смысла, наоборот "нету" делает речь более понятной, часто избавляет рассказчика от необходимости что-то уточнять, при этом всего-то нужно добавить один звук "у" в конце слова.

Пример можно увидеть в песне Childhood's End группы Iron Maiden, с "there is no" вместо "no" было бы не так красиво и перегружено для слушателя:

> The struggle for the power
> A tyrant tries again
> Just what the hell is going on?
> When will it ever end?

> No hope, no life, just pain and fear
> No food, no love, just greed is here

Answer (score 1):

Но есть же и такой вариант, вполне реальный:

*— Есть ли у вас карандаш?*

*— Нет, нету.*

То есть усиление отрицания присутствия.
Но все-таки это какое-то слово-"пасынок".

См. на Грамоте.ру:

**[НЕТУ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83&all=x)**

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, свою мысль. Если вариант (якобы) литературный, то что означает ваша характеристика "слово-пасынок"?! Одно с другим не стыкуется. И аргументируйте, пожалуйста, посерьезнее.

Answer (score 0):

"Нету" считается ошибкой в заданиях ЕГЭ. Там нет никаких акцентов на просторечие и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

**Большой толковый словарь**
**НЕТУ,** в функц. сказ. кого-чего. Разг. =Нет (1 зн.). Детей у нас н. Денег н. ни копейки. Грибов нынче н. Ни в чём удачи н. Житья от него н. <Нетушки, в зн. частицы. Нар.-разг. =Нет. Н., я не согласен.

Итак, слово **нормировано в словаре** с пометкой "разг.". Не стоит забывать, что в литературном языке есть **разные стили.**

Задания же для ЕГЭ решают на других сайтах, и в данном случае речь идет не о ЕГЭ.

Если вы в научной статье используете слово "нету", то это да, слух режет. Ну а в художественной прозе разные встречаются **ситуации,** где это слово вполне уместно и используется для речевой характеристики героев и обозначения самой ситуации.

**В каких реальных случаях** уместен такой стиль, это уже решается индивидуально, в соответствии с вашим чувством языка. Иногда просторечные формы используются как **иронические**, а люди этого не понимают. Ну что ж, это их проблема.

Другими словами, ваш **общий культурный уровень** должен подсказать вам, что и где уместно.